# Performance virtualbox diskfiles vs rawdisk

Tags: virtualbox, performance

Pros and cons with this two ways to make disk for virtual machines on virtualbox

```
$ vboxmanage createhd --format VDI --size ${SIZE} --filename /path/to/disk.vdi
```

and

```
# vboxmanage createrawvmdk -filename /path/to/disk.vmdk -rawdisk /dev/sdX
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

File-pro (which are raw cons):

- Will be cached by the operating system if they fit into ram
- Easier to handle in VirtualBox (i.e. to resize raw you have to recreate the vmdk)
- You might be able to use sparse-files (not sure)

Raw-pro (which are file cons):

- You can use LVs here, giving you full flexibilty
- Access should be faster, since it does not have to pass the filesystem-layer
- Easy to handle outside VirtualBox (e.g. you could use LV-snapshots)

Comment: raw partitions have advantage over files in Because They avoid file system layers. how i can test this?

Comment: @rkmax You could use exactly the same partition either in raw-mode, or put your image there on a filesystem. With an identical VM (just different disk) you should be able to see a small difference when doing a performance-check for disk-io within the VM. You should use a random write pattern. I expect read-performance to be better in a FS-based image if it fits into the cache of the host, though.

Answer (score 5):

These are my `hdparm -tT` timings on a 4x1TB software raid setup running Ubuntu 12.04.1 as the host.

**VM with VDI format:**

Timing cached reads:   23442 MB in  1.97 seconds = 11890.47 MB/sec

Timing buffered disk reads: 346 MB in  3.00 seconds = 115.33 MB/sec

**VM with rawdisk format (50G LV on the same raid device):**

Timing cached reads:   21602 MB in  2.00 seconds = 10812.49 MB/sec

Timing buffered disk reads: 186 MB in  3.02 seconds = 61.69 MB/sec

So rawdisk is about 50% worse performance that VDI, unless I'm doing something completely wrong. Probably going to stick with rawdisk though as the backup option with lvm snapshots seems sane.

Comment: +1 for doing the tests, but I am puzzled by the results.

Comment: If this is due to caching, it is an indication that you may lose plenty of data on a power outage. Far beyond what a journaling filesystem could recover.

Comment: It would be nice to redo these tests using Ubuntu 22.04 and VBox 6.1.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why VDI is faster is the OS cache the image file. And the I/O operations are buffered in the memory.

It would be more fair  if you can close the cache function in virtualbox for this benchmark.

Comment: Why you should disable caching? An enabled cache would be the real life measurement..